# (Guessing Game) Can't Break a loop on Python

Tags: python, function, loops

I was trying to make a guessing game that keep playing if you choose that, but I'm having a problem to break the loop, every time the code reach "`quit()`", the program give me an error

when I used repl:
`repl process died unexpetily`

when I used programiz.com:
`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 42, in <module>   File "<string>", line 40, in game   File "<frozen _sitebuiltins>", line 26, in __call__ SystemExit: None`

so I need some hand here, here is the code

ـــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ

```
import random
import time

Name = input("Hello there!, What is your name? ")

print(f"Hi {Name}! Welcome to the guessing game. I'm going to pick a number between 1 and 100")

def game():
  time.sleep(2)
  print('picking ...')
  time.sleep(2)

  guess = int(input("Alright! What is your guess?: "))
  correct_number = random.randint(1,2)
  guess_count = 1

  while guess != correct_number:
    guess_count += 1
    if guess < correct_number:
      guess = int(input("Nope.Try higher. What is your guess?: "))
    else:
      guess = int(input("Nope.Try lower. What is your guess?: "))

  print(f"Congrats {Name}! The right answer was {correct_number}. It took you {guess_count} guess.")

  time.sleep(3)

  Next_Try = input('''
    Wanna Try again?
  1: Yes!
  2: No thanks
  ''')
  
  while Next_Try:
    if Next_Try == "1":
      game()
    else:
     time.sleep(2)
     print("Thanks for Playing!")
     quit()

game()
```

I have tried `exit()` but still having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `exit` and `quit` basically are both ways to immediately kill the program. In general, they should be used only when things go wrong. In your code, on the `Next_Try` loop at the end, you should use the keyword `break`. That is the proper way to exit a loop. Try this:

```py
  while Next_Try:
    if Next_Try == "1":
      game()
    else:
     time.sleep(2)
     print("Thanks for Playing!")
     break
```

[Here's a link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) to the Python docs that go over more about the `break` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `break` instead of exit()?

```
while Next_Try:
    if Next_Try == "1":
      game()
    else:
     time.sleep(2)
     print("Thanks for Playing!")
     break
```